# Is there a way to make my switch/case fall through to the next case in C#?

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I'm using a switch/case statement to handle some updates for a deployed application. Basically, I want to waterfall through the cases to perform the update from the current running version to the newest version.

From Visual Studio yelling at me, I learned that C# does not allow falling through to the next case (exactly what I'm trying to do). From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1794696/866022), I learned how to do what I want to do. However, it is still apparently an error.

What I've got is

```
switch (myCurrentVersion)
{
    case null:
    case "":
    case "0":
        UpdateToV1();
        goto case "1";
    case "1":
        UpdateToV2();
}
```

I'm getting the following error on the line `case "1":`:

> Error  1   Control cannot fall through from one case label ('case "1":') to another

Am I doing something wrong? How can I force it to fall through?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to add a `break` statement even if it's the last case:

```
switch (myCurrentVersion)
{
    case null:
    case "":
    case "0":
        UpdateToV1();
        goto case "1";
    case "1":
        UpdateToV2();
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 28):

This is a great example of how a poorly worded error message creates confusion. The rule of C# that is actually violated here is not that control has fallen through from one switch section to another; it is that the end point of every switch section must not be reachable. The error, by rights, should have been something like

> Endpoint of switch section for case "1" must not be reachable; consider adding 'break;'

When we revisit the semantic analysis of switch statements for the Roslyn project I'll see if we can change the wording on this a bit to be more clear.

For more analysis of this and related issues, see [my article on the subject](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/13/four-switch-oddities.aspx).

Comment: Ok, I have to ask since you're here and I've always wondered; why isn't `break` implicit?  Fall-through is not allowed, so why require me to write `break` over and over again?  I would love it if fall-through *were* allowed if done so explicitly via some keyword, but short of that, why not save me a bit of typing eh?  In that case you would also need to explicitly allow fall-through for empty case blocks, but that seems like a less common scenario.

Comment: @EdS.: Suppose we make break optional. **People with a C background would then write programs expecting fall-through to work.** But it would not, and the compiler would not tell them otherwise. Making it optional makes the language have a "gotcha". We are working hard to keep the "gotcha" count low in C#. Also, we do *not* require you to write "break" over and over again. You can instead write "throw" or "return" or "goto", or "while(true) {}" -- any of those are just as good as a break as far as the compiler is concerned.

Comment: @EdS.: Incidentally, I am frequently asked questions of the form "the compiler could infer that I meant this thing, so why isn't it optional?" Each one is a judgment call; there is no hard-and-fast rule for when an elision is appropriate. For an example or two,  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631975/c-sharp-using-consts-in-static-classes/2632844#2632844 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092670/why-are-parentheses-required-on-c-sharp-static-constructors/6099409#6099409

Comment: Sure, that's pretty much what I figured (i.e., keeping it as similar as possible to C semantics).  I know it's always a judgement call with things like this.  And yeah, I know you can use other statements that would prevent fallthrough, I was just interested in this case.  Ok then, thanks for the answer.

Comment: If you wanted to minimize gotchas, allowing fall-through would have been more appropriate. That's what people with a C background expect.

Answer (score 5):

You don't have a `break` in your `case "1"` branch.

Answer (score 4):

put a `break;` after  `UpdateToV2();`

Couldnt you get rid of the `goto case "1"` as it will fall through to that anyway?

Comment: No, C# doesn't allow that. I think it's because a good chunk of omitted `break;`s are accidental, and they are trying to prevent people from screwing up (although I really think a warning would be far more appropriate than an error).

Comment: @Jim: Yeah, I think that `break` should have been implicit and fallthrough allowed with the explicit use of some keyword.

Comment: @Ed S. The reason for requiring the explicit `goto` is so reordering the cases won't change the meaning of your code.

Comment: @phoog: Well yes, as it was designed.  I am saying that no-fallthrough should be *implicit*, i.e., I don't have to write `break` over and over again, it just works that way.  If I want fallthrough then I would be required to use some keyword to allow for it.